# Buffalo meat for dining

Tags: food-and-drink, destinations

I just went to Jackson Hole, Wyoming last year and had wonderful buffalo meat as burgers and as steaks. I am looking for other destinations that are known for serving Buffalo for my next vacation. I can but the meat around here where I live in Virginia but I want to go somewhere  buffalo meat is a well known "treat". Can anyone recommend some other places to partake in buffalo meat that aren't just tourist traps? I am looking for fine dining kinda places.

Comment: You want wild buffalo or it doesn't matter?  If it doesn't matter then http://www.cibolafarms.com/

Comment: Looks like I need to take my wife out to dinner...  http://www.allmenus.com/va/riner/257479-brush-creek-buffalo/menu/  Its local :-)

Comment: Here in Canada you can buy bison burgers at the supermarket. http://www.zehrs.ca/LCLOnline/recipes.jsp?breadcrumb=globalsearch&keywords=bison&type=details&recipeId=1683

Comment: Not enough for a reply as you said clearly `meat`, but in Campania, Italy (Naples' region) is quite common _mozzarella di bufala_, cheese made from buffalo's milk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Considering that [American Buffalo's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Bison)
 grazing grounds span nearly entire United States you will find lots of places that grow them and lots of places that can serve them.

There are places where you can [hunt buffalo](http://www.lamontbuffalo.com/).

There are places that grow and sell buffalo meats like [Wild Idea Buffalo Co in South Dakota](http://wildideabuffalo.com/).  But I am sure that if you ask the locals they might just point you to a direction of some hole in the wall mom-and-pop shops that would serve buffalo.

If you are looking for restaurants you can probably find places like [Ruby House](http://www.historicrubyhouse.com/dining.html) all over the place.  I know that South Dakota is somewhat a somewhat touristy state but going to plains states just to eat buffalo doesn't seem like a thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am looking for places that are known for fine dining and not so much hole in the wall places. I hadn't really thought of South Dakota as being a touristy state but will keep it in mind.

Comment: @HeatherWalker I am surprised.  [Mount Rushmore](http://www.nps.gov/moru/index.htm), There is also [Badlands](http://www.nps.gov/badl/index.htm)

Comment: I've seen Bison meat available in many restaurants, but never in a "hole in the wall," as it's usually more expensive than beef.

Comment: I've ate buffalo burgers in a diner in West Yellowstone back in '04. Not exactly upscale, in the UK it'd be pubfood class :)

Comment: @Flimzy Normally where there is not enough of a Buffalo presence you won't find it in a "hole in the wall" types.  But in plain states I am reasonably sure you could.

Comment: @Karlson: I live in a plain state, and even know some Bison farmers, and have never seen it in a "hole in the wall."

Answer (score 7):

[Fuddruckers](http://www.fuddruckers.com/index.php), a national chain in the US with around 200 restaurants, has a menu called [Fudds Exotics](http://www.fuddruckers.com/exotics/) which include buffalo burgers (which were delicious), elk burgers (which I found a little dry), and wild boar burgers (haven't tried yet).  The one nearest me (Phoenix metro area) also had lamb burgers the last time I was there.

[image]